# How to read in an entire string after reading in integer and double?

Tags: java, string

So I have the following inputs:

```
3
3.0
How are you doing
```

And I need to store them to the following variables:

```
int myInt
double myDouble
String myString
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
myInt = scan.nextInt();
myDouble = scan.nextDouble();
myString = scan.nextLine();
```

That works for the Integer and `Double` value but the `String` gave me a NULL value.

Then I tried this:

```
myInt = scan.nextInt();
myDouble = scan.nextDouble();
myString = scan.next();
```

Again it worked for the first two, but the string only holds the first word. How can I read the entire string? Do I need to setup a loop?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`nextLine()` is a bit confusingly named. It doesn't give you the *next* line, but reads up until the next line break it encounters.

After you've called nextDouble(), the scanner is positioned after the `3.0` but *before* the new line, so `nextLine()` reads to the end of that line and gives you an empty result.

You could either use [`skip(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#skip(java.lang.String)) to skip the newline after `3.0`, or just call `nextLine()` once and throw it away:

```
myInt = scan.nextInt();
myDouble = scan.nextDouble();
scan.nextLine(); // Skip the remainder of the double line
myString = scan.nextLine();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that clear a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
myInt = scan.nextInt();
myDouble = scan.nextDouble();
```

instead of using `scanner` to give you the `double and int` use `nextLine()` and cast it manually. `scanner` is not going to the next line that's the problem.

```
 myInt = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
 myDouble = Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine());
 myString = scan.nextLine();
```

Comment: This is the best way to handle input. It allows you to validate the input and tell the user if they entered something wrong, rather than letting the program crash.

Comment: @4castle thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

When you call nextDouble method it reads a double value and advances the scanner accordingly. So, when you call nextDouble your scanner is after the value 3.0 but before the next-line character. Now when you call nextLine() method it advances scanner until it hits the next next-line character and returns whatever was read when the advancement was made. Since your scanner is right before the next-line character, when you call nextLine() method the scanner hits next-line character immediately without reading anything. Hence your nextLine() method returns null.

If your input values are in each line you can follow the suggestion of @Priyamal or you can insert one more nextLine() method call before myString = scan.nextLine(). So, your code for getting the input will look like following:

```
myInt = scan.nextInt();
myDouble = scan.nextDouble();
scan.nextLine();
myString = scan.nextLine();
```